# Parsing the body of a post response, Java

Tags: java, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to implement some methods of a http POST based API. The problem is that I'm not really familiar with the format of the requests and replies. I don't know if its a standard format, that perhaps my apache httpclient can parse for me, or if I have to do it myself.
Basically it looks like this:

```
{
 "key": value,
 "parent": [
  {
    "child1key1": child1value1,
    "child1key2": child1value2,
  },
  {
    "child2key1": child2value1,
    "child2key2": child2value2,
  }
 ]
}
```

What is this format? How do I parse it? I mean I could write a parser myself but I'm assuming I don't really have to.
Also, the request expects the same format, so I would need to be able to build requests on this format as well.

Comment: they are popularly known as JSON.. and you may look at GSON Parser or [Jackson parsers](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JSON, [JavaScript Object Notation.](http://www.json.org/)

There is a lot of json parser for java, i can suggest to you [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)